# Monitoring Power BI report usage/visits when the report is published to Microsoft Teams

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-teams

Our team wants to monitor what Power Bi reports are being used/viewed by our stakeholders. Some of our stakeholders view our Power BI reports through the Power BI app in the browser and some through Microsoft Teams.

When we go to the Report Usage Metrics on the Power BI app in the browser, does it only show the views/report usage metrics for visits done through the Power BI app in the browser and not through Microsoft Teams? We are not sure but we would think it does not include it given the numbers we are seeing.

What are the steps we would need to take in order to see the Report Usage Metrics for the visits on the Power BI reports through Microsoft Teams?

Comment: It should record all interaction with the report if it is from the service and teams. I would test it with a sample report that you only access in team to confirm.

Comment: It seems it is not supported yet. You can track this idea - https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=e5b27ae3-6c1b-4364-9b4e-b903cc68932e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported. You can track the idea here - https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=e5b27ae3-6c1b-4364-9b4e-b903cc68932e